Why 'doing' is not used after 'is'
I'm reading a text and there is sentence which is

Part of what Mee's trying to do is drive home the point that ...

I think 'is' should be followed by some noun terms, so 'driving' should be used.
But in fact, 'drive' is used.
Why is 'drive' used here instead of 'driving'?

What text are you reading? Using the bare infinitive there is an informal construction, although it might be a mistake; using "to drive" would be more usual. But changing it to "driving" would alter the meaning: see the second paragraph of this answer.

Since it's not wrong, but an author's choice, we could go on to ask why "drive home," and not "stress," "make," or "emphasize." What the author is doing by contracting Mee is to "Mee's" is announce the writing as informal.

@StuartF It's a listening transcript of TOFEL. Thank you for your instruction.

"Part of what Mee's trying to do is drive home the point that ..."
This is a use of the bare infinitive. The full version would be
"Part of what Mee is trying to do is to drive home the point that ..."
I.e. Mee is trying to drive home the point. You would not say say "Mee is trying driving home the point".
What justifies the use of the bare infinitive in this instance is that the "to" of "to do" is understood to apply to both verbs.
You could however use "doing" in the following:
Part of what "Mee is trying to do is driving me crazy.", but that would be a different grammatical structure. This is because Mee is trying to do something - he is not trying to drive me crazy. My craziness is incidental to Mee's efforts, not part of them.

"Be" does not take a bare infinitive.  There is an omitted "to".
